# Rails: Associations and reference models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations, strong-parameters

**Background:**
I have two models `User`(Devise model) and `Client`.  I have setup associations such that `Client belongs_to :user` and `User has_one :client`.  I have setup my database such that the clients table has a `user_id` attribute

**Problem:**
In my navbar, once a user is signed in, I want them to be able to access their "profile" which is represented by the `Client` model, however I cannot seem to access the proper client through the `user_params`.  For example `<%= link_to "My Profile", client_path(@user) %>`

This results in the error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"clients", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]` even though the :id should be available since the user is signed in.

I have edited the Devise `sessions_controller` to contain:

```
def configure_sign_in_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
    user_params.permit( :email, :password, :id)
  end
end
```

...but still have no luck.  I have a feeling I'm missing something basic, I just need some help.

Comment: when calling `client_path(@user)`, `@user` is `nil`. Did you set it in your controller? Maybe you meant to use `client_path(current_user)`?

Comment: What does your `routes.rb` file look like regarding users and clients? In your code snippet, what is `@user` being set to in the controller?

Comment: MrYoshi you are correct!  Thank you, that was such a silly mistake -_-.  I need to brush up on my Devise knowledge

Answer (score 0):

> I'm missing something basic

You don't need `@user`, it needs to be [`current_user`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers):

```
<%= link_to "Profile", client_path(current_user) if user_signed_in? %>
```

---

We use a similar pattern (`User has_one Profile`); we made a [`singular resource`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) which negates the need to pass an object:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :client
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
end

#config/routes.rb
resource :profile, only: [:show, :update] #-> url.com/profile

#app/controllers/profile_controller.rb
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  def update
    current_user.update user_params
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(client_attributes: [:x, :y, :z])
  end
end

#app/views/profile/show.html.erb
<%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :client do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :x %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to send requests to... `<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path %>`.

Because you're only allowing the `profile` view for each user, you'll be able to call the `current_user` object for it.